# Rails 5 multiple edit views for one update controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am programming an app for people with Diabetes to calculate the insulin the person needs. That means a user profile consists of his name email and password and also of factors for different times of the day. The database schema is:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180115094430) do

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.string "remember_digest"
    t.boolean "admin"
    t.string "activation_digest"
    t.boolean "activated"
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string "reset_digest"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
    t.float "zero_till_one"
    t.float "one_till_two"
    t.float "two_till_three"
    t.float "three_till_four"
    t.float "four_till_five"
    t.float "five_till_six"
    t.float "six_till_seven"
    t.float "seven_till_eight"
    t.float "eight_till_nine"
    t.float "nine_till_ten"
    t.float "ten_till_eleven"
    t.float "eleven_till_twelve"
    t.float "twelve_till_thirteen"
    t.float "thirteen_till_fourteen"
    t.float "fourteen_till_fifteen"
    t.float "fifteen_till_sixteen"
    t.float "sixteen_till_seventeen"
    t.float "seventeen_till_eightteen"
    t.float "eightteen_till_nineteen"
    t.float "nineteen_till_twenty"
    t.float "twenty_till_twentyone"
    t.float "twentyone_till_twentytwo"
    t.float "twentytwo_till_twentythree"
    t.float "twentythree_till_zero"
  end

end
```

When I create a user, he is just created with name, email and password. When signed up and logged in the user can edit his profile via RESTful routes user/1/edit. I want the user to be able to edit the still empty t.float "zero_till_one" etc. columns via user/1/edit/diabsettings and still be able to use the same  update action inside the users_controller.rb to update the database:

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user

    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

How can I achieve this. Any help highly appreciated.

Best Sebastian

Comment: yes you can do this:- create a edit action and in `edit.html.erb` show all field that should be editable after login and update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- create a edit action

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

2- edit.html.erb

```
<%=form_for @user, :html => { id: "edit_user", class: "your_class"} do |f|%>
  <%=f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'%>
  <%=f.text_field :email,class: 'form-control'%>
  <%=f.text_field :password,class: 'form-control'%>
  <% content_tag :button, :type => :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary' do %>
    Update User
  <% end %>
<%end%>
```

3 - create a edit_diabsettings action

```
  def edit_diabsettings
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

4- in edit_diabsettings.html.erb craete form to edit other than name, email,password:-

```
<%=form_for @user, :html => { id: "edit_diabsettings", class: "your_class"} do |f|%>
  <%=f.text_field :zero_till_one, class: 'form-control'%>
  <%=f.text_field :one_till_two,class: 'form-control'%>
  <%=f.text_field :two_till_three,class: 'form-control'%>

  #.... and so on that should be editable here
  <% content_tag :button, :type => :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary' do %>
    Update User
  <% end %>
<%end%>
```

5- make update action to update all field

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

6- create a private action for user_params

```
private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit!
    end
```

7- as you need to create a separate action for `edit_diabsettings` action in routes.rb

```
get 'user/:id/edit/diabsettings', to: 'users#edit_diabsettings', as: : edit_diabsettings
```

Comment: I already have this. What I need is editing one part of the user params via user/1/edit and the other part via user/1/edit/diabsettings. That means two different routes and two different forms both using the update action for an instance of the User model (@user).

Comment: @SebastianPeter yes you can do this. in this case you should have two forms one for ` user/1/edit ` and one for `user/1/edit/diabsettings.` and in both form specify only those field that should be editable. as i m going to modify the answer. let me know for further guidance.

Comment: @SebastianPeter i have created two form for two action as mention you by having two routes, and both form will go the same action to `update`. because `=form_for @user` will let you hit the `update` action if `@user` object is already exist. otherwise it will hit `create`  action. hope it helped you. feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you

Comment: Thanks a lot thats what I needed. in routes.rb how do I declare the matching route which includes the user id ?

Comment: @SebastianPeter i think you have already `user/1/edit` action you only need to create a another action for `edit_diabsettings` and this can be done by `get 'user/:id/edit/diabsettings', to: 'users#edit_diabsettings'` as we create normal route. thank you.

Comment: Your Help is highly appreciated. Many Thanks

Comment: I now have the problem that there is no named helper. How can i link to the 'user/:id/edit/diabsettings' path??? Thanks in advance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163256/discussion-between-sebastian-peter-and-gabbar).

Comment: @Sebastian Peter i have modified answer for rouetes and when you will run `rake routes` on console you will get named route helper fot `edit_diabsettings` action and you can use it as `edit_diabsettings_path(@user)`

Comment: Thanks.  OMG. I knew this. Named Routes. Sorry for asking the obvious